# Why does a sentence can be followed by "doing something"?

Tags: prepositions

[Falling](http://www.novelsearch12.com/read/this-is-falling-falling-1/17495)

Take a look at the following:

> ... and my head gets a little fuzzy **looking** at him.

If it's up to me to make this sentence, it would be

> ... my head gets a little fuzzy by looking at him.

So, I don't understand why it can directly link "looking at ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence means that the head is getting fuzzy **while** you are looking at him. Both of the acts are simultaneously happening.

The second sentence uses **"by"**, which means that your head gets fuzzy **because** you looked at him. The fuzzy head is something that probably happened soon after you looked at him, but not necessary at the same time though.